# Is it correct to say "Open shift"?

Tags: phrase-usage, business-language, finance

Is it correct to say open shift and close shift or is it more preferred to use begin shift and close shift? By opening shift, I mean it from the perspective of the worker that uses a cash register or cash drawer: https://www.thebalancesmb.com/balancing-a-cash-register-2890536

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not normal usage.

We would say:

> I am going to work the ***opening*** *shift*.
>   I am going to work the ***closing*** *shift*.

Or (in context), we would say:

> I am going to *open* this morning.
>   I am going to *close* tonight.

But neither ***open*** *shift* nor ***close*** *shift* are used.